# Pre-Populate a new JIRA project with cookie-cutter components, milestones and tasks/features

Tags: project-management, jira

I have a team who will be working on deploying several websites with a similar structure (they're all based on the same core software). Each launch would likely be a separate JIRA project. Since the components, milestones and several tasks need to be repeated for each site, I'd also like to have a method for pre-populating a new project to get the ball rolling quickly.

Does anyone have suggestions on ways to accomplish this?

I do not currently have JIRA Admin rights, but if it is absolutely necessary, I may be able to get them.

I cannot at this time take suggestions for other task management utilities because the company I work for has integrated JIRA into many facets of the org.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you use the jira cli ?
https://plugins.atlassian.com/plugin/details/6398

We are using it to pre populate JIRA with data to test out customizations we are making for our customers.

You can equally use it to populate it with components, predefined issues, ...
It's pretty straightforward to do, and as long as RPC is enabled on JIRA, you can actually start to use it without particular admin rights.

Francis